# Prepopulating Edit Form in PHP using PDO

Tags: php, database, pdo

I was working with my update form and I want to prepopulate my form with data that the user entered previously. I essentially used the same code that I used for my page that displayed my query results, however, instead of getting the result back, I get an error that says this:

`Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\this\is\a\path\update.php on line 64`

Here is my code:

update.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        require "../resources/config.php";
        require "../resources/common.php";

        try {
            $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = ?";

            $id = $_GET['id'];

            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute(array($id));

            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        }

        catch(PDOException $error) {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>

<h2 class="display-3 text-center mb-5">Change a Phone Number</h2>

<h1><?php echo ($result['firstname']); ?></h1>
<form class="w-50 mx-auto" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

<a class="btn btn-secondary d-block w-25 mx-auto" href="index.php">Back to home</a>
```

view.php

```
<?php

    try {   
        require "../resources/config.php";
        require "../resources/common.php";

        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM people";

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    } 

    catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $error->getMessage();
    }

?>

<?php require "../resources/templates/header.php" ?>

<?php if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
    <h2 class="display-2 text-center mb-4">Contacts</h2>

    <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email Address</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
                <!-- <th scope="col">Date Added</th> -->
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <td><?php echo escape($row["firstname"]); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($row["lastname"]); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($row["email"]); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($row["phonenumber"]); ?></td>
                    <!-- <td><?php echo escape($row["date"]); ?> </td> -->
                    <td style="letter-spacing: 20px;">
                        <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?>'">
                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                        </a> 
                        <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?>'">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?> 
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php } else { ?>
        <blockquote>No results found.</blockquote>
    <?php } 

?> 
    <a class="btn btn-secondary d-block w-25 mx-auto mb-4" href="create.php">Add a new number</a>
    <a class="btn btn-secondary d-block w-25 mx-auto" href="index.php">Back to home</a>


<?php require "../resources/templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

How do I improve my code and fetch my data correctly while also using prepared statements and PDO at the same time?

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: Creating a new database connection in each and every file, every single time you need to do anything, is really a problematic way of doing this. Generally you should isolate your connection code to a common library, not have N instances of the same boilerplate code.

Comment: Verify that `$row` has the data you need with `var_dump`. You may be getting the wrong values. This is the perils of `SELECT *`. You never know what you're going to get.

Comment: @tadman When I used `var_dump`, looking at the array, all of my information is being pulled over correctly. Am I missing something like a `htmlspecialchars` or something?

Comment: Hi, in the update.php file, replace `fetchAll` with `fetch` to fetch only one record, `fetchAll` fetch an array of records, should work, but you may reorganize your common code into functions as pointed by fellows.

Comment: @ankabout That was my issue! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ankabout That sounds like a good answer.

Comment: No problem @Kevin

Comment: Yea he thanked me that's enough I think @tadman you did some good notes too.

Comment: @ankabout What I mean is this question can't be "answered" until there's an answer, and I think you nailed it. Posting even a small answer helps flag it properly and can steer others with a similar problem to this solution. Helps close the loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update.php file, use [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead of [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

`fetchAll` fetch an array of records, where each record is represented by an array, so it returns an array of arrays or an empty array if it doesn't find any matching record.

While `fetch` fetch only one record represented by an array, also only one record is returned even if the database returns more than one record, since your SQL query is using a `WHERE id = <id>` clause you are expecting one record to be returned (or zero), so `fetch` is the natural function to use.

On the other hand `fetch` may return false in case no record is found for that `<id>`, so you should enclose your HTML inside an `if ($result)` clause and show a "No record found" in the `else` clause as you did in the view.php file.

Other than that your use of PDO prepared statements look correct to me.